# Prevent draggable items to go outside of container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to prevent draggable divs to go outside of container div.

This is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CAEV5/268/) to explain this issue further.

i tried something like this in my code but this will stop my code working:

```
  if($('#set').offset().left > 50) 
  { 
     $( '#set div' ).draggable( 'option',  'revert', true ).trigger( 'mouseup' );
  }
```

could someone please advise on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the option

```
containment: "parent" // Or any selector; "parent" refers to the immediate parent
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment

like:

```
$( '#set div' ).draggable({
   revert : true,
   containment: "parent"
}).trigger( 'mouseup' );
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/CAEV5/269/)

Comment: I need to make the same div's resizable too... could you please let me know why when I add `$( "#set div" ).draggable().resizable({...});` to my code, nothing works properly?

Comment: @rooz welcome to the infinite bugs of jQuery UI and disappearing child elements when both on .resize() and .draggable()

Comment: @rooz P.S. in css use the `>` selector when targeting the child DIV elements. In any case you'll have to find a way to prevent the sibling elements from collapsing. I have no time right now.

Comment: @rooz so far: http://jsfiddle.net/CAEV5/271/ but you can clearly see the issue. perhaps asking a new SO question?

Answer (score 1):

i have changed this

```
  <div id="set1">
        <div id='set'>
            <div data-need="1"></div>
            <div data-need="2"></div>
            <div data-need="3"></div>
            <div data-need="4"></div>
           <div data-need="5"></div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

and added this in js  `containment: "#set1 div",`

```
$(function() {
  $( "#set div" ).draggable({ 

    containment: "#set1 div",
    stack: "#set div",
      stop: function(event, ui) {
          var pos_x = ui.offset.left;
          var pos_y = ui.offset.top;
          var need = ui.helper.data("need");

          console.log(pos_x);
          console.log(pos_y);
          console.log(need);

          //alert( pos_x);

          //Do the ajax call to the server
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "your_php_script.php",
              data: { x: pos_x, y: pos_y, need_id: need}
            }).done(function( msg ) {
              alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
            }); 
      }
  });

});
```

This is working as per your requirement

[here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CAEV5/270/)